# How to format using regular expression and str.replace

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am using this regular expression

```
var str = "The requirements of this chapter apply to the following: (1)New buildings or portions thereof used as health care occupancies (see 1.4.1) (2)Additions made to, or used as, a health care occupancy (see 4.6.6 and 18.1.1.4) Exception: The requirement of 18.1.1.1.1 shall not apply to additions classified as occupancies other than health care that are separated from the health care occupancy in accordance with 18.1.2.1(2) and conform to the requirements for the specific occupancy in accordance with Chapters 12 through 17 and Chapters 20 through 42, as appropriate. (3)Alterations, modernizations, or renovations of existing health care occupancies (see 4.6.7 and 18.1.1.4) (4)Existing buildings or portions thereof upon change of occupancy to a health care occupancy (see 4.6.11) Exception*: Facilities where the authority having jurisdiction has determined equivalent safety has been provided in accordance with Section 1.5.";
str = str.replace(/(\(\d+\)|exception\s*\:*)/gi, "<br /><br />$1&nbsp");
```

where I get output like this

> 18.1.1.1.1 The requirements of this chapter apply to the following:
>
> (1) New buildings or portions thereof used as health care occupancies
>   (see 1.4.1)
>
> (2) Additions made to, or used as, a health care occupancy (see 4.6.6
>   and 18.1.1.4)
>
> Exception:  The requirement of 18.1.1.1.1 shall not apply to additions
>   classified as occupancies other than health care that are separated
>   from the health care occupancy in accordance with 18.1.2.1
>
> (2)  and conform to the requirements for the specific occupancy in
>   accordance with Chapters 12 through 17 and Chapters 20 through 42, as
>   appropriate.
>
> (3) Alterations, modernizations, or renovations of existing health
>   care occupancies (see 4.6.7 and 18.1.1.4)
>
> (4) Existing buildings or portions thereof upon change of occupancy to
>   a health care occupancy (see 4.6.11)

But my desired output is

> 18.1.1.1.1 The requirements of this chapter apply to the following:
>
> (1) New buildings or portions thereof used as health care occupancies
>   (see 1.4.1)
>
> (2) Additions made to, or used as, a health care occupancy (see 4.6.6
>   and 18.1.1.4)(2)  and conform to the requirements for the specific
>   occupancy in accordance with Chapters 12 through 17 and Chapters 20
>   through 42, as appropriate.
>
> Exception:  The requirement of 18.1.1.1.1 shall not apply to additions
>   classified as occupancies other than health care that are separated
>   from the health care occupancy in accordance with 18.1.2.1
>
> (3) Alterations, modernizations, or renovations of existing health
>   care occupancies (see 4.6.7 and 18.1.1.4)
>
> (4) Existing buildings or portions thereof upon change of occupancy to
>   a health care occupancy (see 4.6.11)

Here it break the line of `(2)` again of this value "(see 4.6.6 and 18.1.1.4)***(2)***" .how can i get this format?

Comment: When you post, please use the markup for code! As it stands it is unreadable.

Comment: TL;DR: He wants to split his string on the numbered lines (the start of the line), but not the `(2)` that's part of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regex, try to only split on `\(\d)\`s that have a space before them:

```
str = str.replace(/(\s\(\d+\)|exception\s*\:*)/gi, "<br /><br />$1&nbsp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for something that isn't a closing paren before the number in parens. You have to fake it out on the exception part. I decided to find a non-alphabetic before the word "exception". That makes sure its a whole word, at least on the front. (Though, to be fair, I can't think of an English word that ends with "expression".)

Note how JavaScript numbers the matched strings by the ordering of the parens in the regular expression and not by the order of the parens as the matcher goes through finding things that match. So the parts that aren't matched (because of the or) still count in the $1, $2, $3 and $4.

```
str = str.replace(/([^)])(\(\d+\))|([^a-zA-Z])(exception\s*\:*)/gi, "$1$3<br /><br />$2$4&nbsp");
```

You can test Javascript regular expressions here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html

(That's what I did to get that expression working.)

Answer (score 0):

You could incorporate `(?:\(\d+\))*` into your regex, unless I've missed what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
str = str.replace(/(\(\d+\)|exception\s*\:*)(\S)/gi, "<br /><br />$1&nbsp;$2");
```

It seems working: see http://jsbin.com/otuteh/1/edit